# Calculate average deal size from table of deals, while excluding initial retainers

Tags: excel, powerquery

We're a hiring agency and I have a table in Excel containing information about deals with clients for hiring employees for their companies. Most of the deals have only one record in the table.

There are some special deals: **retainers**.
Here, there will be two records for one deal in the table. The first record shows the retainer that is paid by the client, and the second record shows the completion fees paid, which is the remaining fees after the retainer.

To be able to identify these records, I have added a column called **Retainer ID**, which will hold the same ID for the two records of the same deal.

I want to calculate the average deal size for each billing month, quarter, and year, considering each deal as one entity (Retainer Fee and Completion Fee combined) and excluding the initial retainers.

That is if the retainer (10,000) for a deal was paid in January 2022, and the completion fees (20,000) came in February 2022, then this deal should only be considered in the calculations for February 2022. The size of this deal is to be counted as 30,000.

| Candidate Name | Client | Role Owner | Delivery Type | Billing Date | Fees | Retainer ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Retainer Fee- Project management search | ABC | Tobi | Retained Search | 2023-01-01 | 10000 | 1 |
| Jane Smith | GHI | Tobi | Contingent Search | 2023-02-01 | 25000 |  |
| Michael Brown | JKL | Josh | Spec. Introduction | 2023-02-01 | 20000 |  |
| Completion fee - John Doe | ABC | Tobi | Retained Search | 2023-03-01 | 20000 | 1 |
| Mary Johnson | STU | Jac | Contingent Search | 2023-03-01 | 20000 |  |
| Robert Smith | DEF | Josh | Excl. Contingent | 2023-03-01 | 15000 |  |
| Retainer Fee- Project management search | DEF | Adam | Retained Search | 2023-03-01 | 10000 | 2 |
| John Doe | ABC | Tobi | Contingent Search | 2023-04-01 | 12000 |  |
| Jane Smith | GHI | Tobi | Contingent Search | 2023-04-01 | 18000 |  |
| Michael Brown | JKL | Josh | Spec. Introduction | 2023-04-01 | 22000 |  |
| Retainer Fee- Senior analyst | ABC | Tobi | Retained Search | 2023-05-01 | 18000 | 3 |
| Mary Johnson | STU | Jac | Contingent Search | 2023-05-01 | 22000 |  |
| Robert Smith | DEF | Josh | Excl. Contingent | 2023-05-01 | 14000 |  |
| Completion Fee- Jane Smith | DEF | Adam | Retained Search | 2023-05-01 | 9000 | 2 |
| John Doe | ABC | Tobi | Contongent Search | 2023-06-01 | 11000 |  |
| Jane Smith | GHI | Tobi | Contingent Search | 2023-06-01 | 19000 |  |
| Michael Brown | JKL | Josh | Spec. Introduction | 2023-06-01 | 21000 |  |
| John Doe | ABC | Tobi | Spec. Introduction | 2023-07-01 | 19000 |  |
| Mary Johnson | STU | Jac | Contingent Search | 2023-07-01 | 23000 |  |
| Robert Smith | DEF | Josh | Excl. Contingent | 2023-07-01 | 16000 |  |

Expected Output:

| Billing Year | Billing Quarter | Billing Month | No. of Deals | Total Fees (GBP) | Average Deal Size (GBP) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | Q1 | January | 0 | £0.00 | £0.00 |
| 2023 | Q1 | February | 2 | £45,000.00 | £22,500.00 |
| 2023 | Q1 | March | 3 | £65,000.00 | £21,666.67 |
| 2023 | Q2 | April | 3 | £52,000.00 | £17,333.33 |
| 2023 | Q2 | May | 3 | £55,000.00 | £18,333.33 |
| 2023 | Q2 | June | 3 | £51,000.00 | £17,000.00 |
| 2023 | Q3 | July | 3 | £58,000.00 | £19,333.33 |

I've tried to solve this by using a SUMIF formula, but it doesn't seem to work. I have to solve this without using macros.

Comment: Can you use power query?

Comment: It is to be stored on Sharepoint, so whatever solution we use must work on Sharepoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I note that based on your output, if there is only a single entry per retainer fee ID, you don't want to count that at all in your monthly data.

I don't have Sharepoint, but there are numerous articles about using Power Query and/or Excel and/or Power BI with Sharepoint. Power Query and Power BI both have connectors to Sharepoint to access data there.

And doing this in Power Query is pretty straightforward.

I am describing how to do this starting with a table in Excel. Once it is working OK, you can replace the data source with Sharepoint (or do this in Power BI to have access to a variety of report templates):

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next line to reflect Sharepoint Query
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Candidate Name", type text}, {"Client", type text}, {"Role Owner", type text}, 
        {"Delivery Type", type text}, {"Billing Date", type date}, 
        {"Fees", Int64.Type}, {"Retainer ID", Int64.Type}}),

//Remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Candidate Name", "Client", "Role Owner", "Delivery Type"}),

//Group by Retainer ID and consolidate all fees to latest date
//  However, if there is only a single fee, then it is a Retainer fee and 
//   not to be included
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Retainer ID"}, {
        {"Reduce", each if Table.RowCount(_) = 1 then null 
            else if [Retainer ID]{0} = null then _
            else Table.FromRecords(
                {Record.FromList(
                    {List.Max([Billing Date]), List.Sum([Fees]), List.First([Retainer ID])}, 
                     Table.ColumnNames(_))
                }), 
            type table [Billing Date=nullable date, Fees=nullable number, Retainer ID=nullable number]}}),

//Expand the grouped table
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Retainer ID"}),
    #"Expanded Reduce" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Reduce", {"Billing Date", "Fees"}),

//Remove blank rows which were the solo retainer fees
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = 
        Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Reduce", each [Billing Date] <> null),

//Group by Date and add the aggregations
//If your date data is not always the first of the month, may need to add an extra year/date column for grouping
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Removed Blank Rows", {"Billing Date"}, {
        {"Billing Year", each Date.Year([Billing Date]{0}), Int64.Type},
        {"Billing Quarter", each Number.ToText(Date.QuarterOfYear([Billing Date]{0}),"'Q'0") }, 
        {"Billing Month", each Date.MonthName([Billing Date]{0}), type text}, 
        {"No. of Deals", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}, 
        {"Total Fees (GBP)", each List.Sum([Fees]), Currency.Type}, 
        {"Average Deal Size (GBP)", each List.Average([Fees]), Currency.Type}}),

    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows1",{{"Billing Date", Order.Ascending}}),

//Remove unneeded column
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Billing Date"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2"
```

***Output from your Input***
[image]

Comment: The code is working well, thank you. Still trying to figure out how to make this run with Power Query reading data from an Excel file on Sharepoint and then writing back to another tab in the same Excel file.

Comment: @TJ Unfortunately, I cannot help you with Sharepoint. I believe reading the Excel file into PQ is straightforward using the Sharepoint connector, but I have no experience myself so cannot advise you as to how to write the results back to the Excel file.